# Remove an event listener with parameter on dismount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component with an event listener, *and that listener passes a variable*. Like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="footnote-anchor"]');
  links.forEach((link) => {
    // assume linkNumber === the number at the end of link's id
    // that is, link 1 will be paired up with info-window 1
    const linkNumber = this.getLinkNumber(link)
    const infoWindow = document.getElementById(`info-window-${linkNumber}');
    this.setupHover(link, infoWindow);
  });

}

// hovering over link will turn infoWindow pink
setupHover = (link, infoWindow) => {
  const doHover = () => this.linkHover(infoWindow);
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', doHover, false);
}

linkHover = (infoWindow) => {
  infoWindow.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
}
```

The elements above are pulled from the DOM itself, which looks like this:

```
<div id="info-window-1">Informative!</div>
<div id="info-window-2">Less so!</div>
...
<a href='' id='link-1'>Link 1</a>
<a href='' id='link-2'>Link 2</a>
```

As written, this works. However, I don't know how pass `infoWindow`via the event listener *and then remove said event listener* on dismount.

Variations on this question have been asked before, and I have tried a number of the answers, but none of them have worked.

Thanks!

EDIT: I should also note that a lot of this is required because I don't have a lot of control over the data. It's a big chunk of HTML that needs to be parsed however I can manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your `link` and `infoWindow` in `this`, so that you have a reference to use for later.

```
componentDidMount() {
  ...
  // Assume link is an <a href>
  // Assume infoWindow is a <div>. Also assume there is one infoWindow per link, 
  // but the two are not directly related.
  this.infoWindow = something_here;
  this.link = something_here;
  this.setupHover();
}

setupHover = () => {
  this.link.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.linkHover, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.link.removeEventListener('mouseenter', this.linkHover, false);
}

linkHover = () => {
  this.infoWindow.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
}
```

Comment: I think that's a solid idea, but In `componentDidMount()`, `infoWindow` is undefined. Maybe `this.doHover` could be defined in `setupHover()`?

Comment: it was assuming you had `infoWindow` in your `componentDidMount`. But yes, you can do that in there as well. I have updated my answer, see if it helps.

Comment: I've simplified my example quite a bit, so I think an important factor slipped past. Assume there are many `infoWindow`s, one per link and that `infoWindow` is selected _based on which link is clicked_. Thus, `setupHover` requires both of its arguments, as written. I'll try to edit my question so that this is clear.

Comment: Maybe you can use arrays to represent the combined-`link`-`infoWindow` parameter. Or even include a function that does the style setting in the list. The list might look like `[{link:, handler: () => { handler here}}, {}]`. I would have properly written you an answer but I have some works to attend to. See if this works. If it doesn't I will update my answer as soon as I am free.

Answer (score 0):

What about just the reverse?

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.teardownHover(link, infoWindow)
}

teardownHover = (link, infoWindow) => {
  const doHover = () => this.linkHover(infoWindow);
  link.removeEventListener('mouseenter', doHover, false);
}

linkHover = (infoWindow) => {
  infoWindow.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
}
```

I'm not sure if you need to redefine the `doHover` and `linkHover` functions, but I don't see why the above wouldn't properly remove the eventlistener on unmount.

Comment: I considered this, but I don't think `() => this.linkHover(infoWindow) === () => this.linkHover(infoWindow)`, thus `removeEventListener` will be looking for the wrong listener.

Maybe I'm wrong about that?